# Read and write a buffer of unsigned char to a file in C?

Tags: c, file, io, char, unsigned

The following code writes an array of unsigned char (defined as `byte`) to a file:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
void ToFile(byte *buffer, size_t len)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        fprintf(f, "%u", buffer[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

How do I read the file back from `out.txt` into a buffer of `byte`? The goal is to iterate the buffer `byte` by `byte`. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to read it back, I wouldn't use `%u` to write it out. `%u` is going to be variable width output, so a `1` takes one character, and a `12` takes two, etc. When you read it back and see `112` you don't know if that's three characters (1, 1, 2), or two (11, 2; or 1, 12) or just one (112). If you need an ASCII file, you would use a fixed width output, such as `%03u`. That way each byte is always 3 characters. Then you could read in a byte at a time with `fscanf("%03u", buffer[i])`.

Comment: Hey @lurker thanks! How can I accept this as the answer? Your post helped me understand what I need to do exactly.

Comment: Thanks. I posted it as an answer, which is what I should have done originally.

Answer (score 2):

*How do I read the file back from out.txt into a buffer of byte? The goal is to iterate the buffer byte by byte. Thanks.*

***Something similar to this*** should work for you.  (Not debugged, doing this away from my compiler)

```
void FromFile(byte *buffer, size_t len)
{

    FILE *fOut = fopen("out.txt", "rb");  
    int cOut;

    int i = 0;
    if (fOut == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cOut = fgetc(fOut);
    while(cOut != EOF)
    {
        buffer[i++] = cOut;  //iterate buffer byte by byte

        cOut = fgetc(fOut);   
    }

    fclose(fOut);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read it back, I wouldn't use `%u` to write it out. `%u` is going to be variable width output, so a 1 takes one character, and a `12` takes two, etc. When you read it back and see `112` you don't know if that's three characters (1, 1, 2), or two (11, 2; or 1, 12) or just one (112). If you need an ASCII file, you would use a fixed width output, such as %03u. That way each byte is always 3 characters. Then you could read in a byte at a time with `fscanf("%03u", buffer[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could (and should) use `fread()` and `fwrite()` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) for transferring raw memory between `FILE` s and memory.

To determine the size of the file (to advise fread() how many bytes it should read) use `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END)` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to place the cursor to the end of the file and read its size with `ftell(f)` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/). Don't forget to jump back to the beginning with `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)` for the actual reading process.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the implementation must be in C.

Comment: All the mentioned functions are part of the standard C library (/the stdio.h). They are just documented on the cplusplus.com website. Include stdio.h and you can use them in any C program.